# Started running after 5 years of doing nothing

Tags: running, pain, foot-pain, stiffness

I've been working as a software developer since 5 years ago, and since then I've spent at least 9 hours daily sit down with the computer. I'm not overweight, but I've some abdominal fat that I want to get rid of. Last week I started running, I do 1 hour of running per day at the park. Usually I do one round running, one round walking and so on, until I get tired.

The issue is that my legs are hurting pretty bad, I mean, It's not a bad pain, I guess that's normal after being 5 years sit most of the day. But my concern here is if I should do this daily or if I should have a break every other day to let my legs heal a little bit. I don't wanna take any day off since I've built the habit and I don't wanna get lazy again.

**UPDATE**

The pain is specifically in this areas:

[image]

I also feel some pain in the thighs but it goes away after I strech. Both the pain and stiffness is in the muscles. As I said, I think that this is pretty common having in mind that I don't exercise in five years.

Any tip is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is it muscle `pain` or joint `pain`? Muscle `stiffness` or joint `stiffness`? As you also have the `foot-pain` tag. Where is the foot-pain? Ankles, metatarsals etc?

Comment: @Y12K Thanks, I updated my question

Comment: @Raditz_35 Yeah, I guess that's an option as well.

Comment: Sounds to me like it is DOMS (delayed onset muscle soreness). However, whilst exercising is great - you're doing a lot very soon, without giving your body chance to recover. This will very likely end in injury, and you will then have to take more time off than you would otherwise between runs. So, yes, you should take some time off between runs - ideally a few days for any muscle soreness to subside, before alternating running days and rest days, then build up to back-to-back runs.